# OnMembersAddedAsync is not getting called

Tags: events, botframework, direct-line-botframework, web-chat

I have Bot developed in .NET core 3.1 c#. I am sending Adaptive card in OnMembersAddedAsync. It ix expected that as soon as end customer open chat control it should send Adaptive card. This is working well in Azure web chat control & emulator. But when I added it web site and open chat control in web site it will not work. Control will wait for end customer to send some message & then it sends card.  In  console log of BotFrame.html I can see that DIRECT_LINE connection is established :

```
DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_PENDING
DIRECT_LINE/UPDATE_CONNECTION_STATUS
DIRECT_LINE/UPDATE_CONNECTION_STATUS
DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLING
DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED
```

My code for BotFrame.html is :

```
     const store = window.WebChat.createStore( {}, ( { dispatch } ) => next => async action => {
            console.log(action.type);
            if ( action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY' ) {…..
}
}
```

Even in Bot Logs I cannot see OnMembersAddedAsync is called unless customer sends message. Am I missing anything. Same is working well in Azure web chat control & emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This sample, [04.api/a.welcome-event](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/04.api/a.welcome-event), demonstrates best practice on how to setup Web Chat and your bot for sending a welcome message.

In short, as shown in the sample, you will send an event to your bot when direct line connects your bot and the client.

When the event is received by the bot, it will trigger the bot to send the actual welcome message/card/activity to the user via the client.

**In Web Chat**

```js
const store = window.WebChat.createStore({}, ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
  if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED') {
  // When we receive DIRECT_LINE/CONNECT_FULFILLED action, we will send an event activity using WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT
    dispatch({
      type: 'WEB_CHAT/SEND_EVENT',
      payload: {
        name: 'webchat/join',
        value: { language: window.navigator.language }
      }
    });
}
```

**In Your Bot**

```js
if (context.activity.name === 'webchat/join') {
  await context.sendActivity('Welcome, friend!!');
}
```

Hope of help!